# single background agent for multiple apps(signed with the same certificate) in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-agents

I am a beginner to Windows Phone 8 development. 
My current project involves a background agent retrieving text data from online server on regular intervals and pushing them to several apps at once.
All these apps will be signed and wrapped with the same certificate to make it easier for the agent to communicate.

So my question is : *Can we have a single background agent for multiple apps(signed with the same certificate) in windows phone 8?*

Comment: No, you can't. Apps are isolated in Windows Phone.

Comment: Do you really need this as a background service on the device? Could you have it as a job on the server and then send raw push notifications to the apps? These can be purely data triggers, and not a toast notification the user sees.

Comment: You can have multiple applications listening for the same toast/push  notifications. If you configure the applications to use the same Certs. There are quite a few different tutorials sending toast notifications on Azure, this is where I would start.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try sending push notifications to all my apps.